# How can I autocomplete unique values from a list in Ruby on Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'd like each new title record in my application to have an ISBN field which autocompletes, using values from a table (I can import a [CSV](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file). The trick is that each new autocompletion needs to use a unique ISBN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your model, use `validates_uniqueness_of :isbn`

Andy raises some good questions though!

Answer (score 1):

If you already have the ISBN values in a table, and the ISBN is a key field (which it certainly should be, since ISBNs are unique?) then really you're not creating a new record, are you?

Wouldn't it be better to read your CSV file into your table beforehand, creating records for each of the ISBNs, and have your app update these records, rather than create new ones?

Comment: The ISBN isn't a key field, no. A title record can be created without an ISBN, for instance, if a contract record which has_many titles is created before the ISBNs have been allocated. And some publishers use the same ISBN for the print and the ebook version of a work (stupid, but true). Finally, my app caters for non-book products too, such as maps, so those 'title' records wouldn't have an ISBN. But your response has given me some food for thought, thank you!